# Establecer un punto en el grafico y decir las coordenadas del mismo sin reconocer el valor de X pero de y si en matplotlib python 3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Espero que me puedan ayudar con este inconveniente especifico:

Les presento el problema, requiero de un grafico de puntos cartesiano reconocer un punto especial que esta en el eje y=60 pero no se sabe el valor de x=??, cabe aclarar que el programa debe buscar este valor x.

la idea es que de un grafico de puntos, que se unen atraves de lineas este grafico pasa por el punto de la grafica (x,60) pero que el programa debe mostrarme el valor de X.

les presento el codigo, espero me ayuden muchas gracias.

```
from math import *
from numpy import *

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter



fig, ax = plt.subplots()
datosx=[2.380,0.840,0.590,0.420,0.250,0.177,0.149,0.125,0.074,0.060]
datosy=[96.63,94.42,92.33,89.47,86.39,75.52,72.31,68.87,66.35,60]
dt = 0.01
x = np.arange(0.0, 100.0, dt)
ax.semilogx(datosx,datosy)

ax.plot(datosx, datosy, marker = 'o', mfc='yellow', c='black')
ax.plot(10, 60, marker = 'o', mfc='yellow', c='black')
ax.set_ylim(0.00, 100)
ax.set_xlim(100, 0.01)


#D60
#if min(datosy)<=60:
i=float()
i= (i>0) 
#i=range(0,100)
ax.plot(i,60.0, marker = 'o',mfc="yellow", c="black")
ax.annotate('D60', xy=(i, 60.0), xytext=(i, 70.0),
          arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", facecolor='black'))

ax.plot(i,30.0, marker = '^',mfc="yellow", c="black")  
ax.annotate('D30', xy=(i, 30), xytext=(i, 40),
          arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", facecolor='black'))

ax.plot(i,10.0, marker = '*',mfc="yellow", c="black")         
ax.annotate('D10', xy=(i, 10), xytext=(i, 20.0),
          arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", facecolor='black'))
     

ax.set_xlabel('Diametro del Tamiz [mm]')
ax.set_ylabel('% Pasa')
ax.set_title("Analisis Granulometrico")
ax.grid(axis=("both"))
plt.show()
```